# Do we really need a [mac] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently received a suggested edit on one of my posts (which I had tagged [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx)) adding in a new [mac](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) tag, which has only been used once before.

Do we really need this tag? Isn't the [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) tag enough?

Comment: I shot down a few of these suggested edits. I agree that we don't need a mac tag. The "mac" tag does nothing that the "osx" tag doesn't do already.

Answer (score 11):

No, the tag `osx` is enough. Mac isn't software but hardware. Osx is the software/OS running on macs.

Comment: I think you should say "No", otherwise it sounds like you're saying we need a mac tag (at least, it sounds like that at first).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Jordi Kroon's suggestion:

We need a good tag wiki.
So that noone uses **osx** for hardware and **mac** for software.

We should blacklist the tag **mac**, and instead have a tag **mac-hardware**.
and a **mac-os** for operating system.

Possibly where mac-os is synonymised to **osx** (or the latest mac OS),
but as comments point out this has issues.
Instead puttign a note in the **osx** tag wiki saying Strongly consider using the **mac-os** tag if this is not specifically for osx, but for any mac-os.
Please do not use both.

Comment: Making it to the latest mac OS will cause problems later on in the future since Apple does make new OS's a lot and changing the tag for every version is a pain.

Comment: This is a software recomendation site, I don't think the hardware platform (except it the case of architecture (arm vs. x86)) will ever be relevant. The [tag:mac] tag should probably just be a synonym for [tag:osx] and this will solve the need for a wiki too.

Comment: I think there are a very small number of hardware questions that might crop up, eg: Looking for nvidea driver for Macbook must be open source etc.
Not many though. I'm not super keen on this suggestion any more (even though i wrote it).
However I also disargee with mac==osx