# Make a [osx] synonym for [macos]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags duplicate tags: [macos](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) and [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx). These tags should be linked.

The [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) tag has more questions, however [macos](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) has also question tagged. We could re-tag the existing question, but on the other hand, the operating system for Mac is now called macOS, not OS X, so I'm not sure which tag should be synonym of which.

Comment: For reference, an older discussion: [Do we really need a \[mac\] tag?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/172/60)

Answer (score 3):

I am in favour of retagging all non-version-specific osx questions to macos, and making osx a synonym of macos.

If we have version-specific osx questions, for instance OS X 10.4, then we can create a tag osx-10.4 for instance.